# How can I send in-body images in a mail using python?

Tags: python, image, email, attachment

how can i send in-body attached images in a mail using python?
I found this: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html but it has not an example with images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [big example](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#id2) of "how to send the entire contents of a directory as an email message". The image in the file `fp` is converted into the message part `msg` here:

```
msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
```

and then the message part is attached to the outer message here:

```
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
outer.attach(msg)
```

If you want the image to appear inline rather than as an attachment, you should set its `Content-Disposition` to `inline` instead of `attachment`.

(If you want to create HTML messages that display attached images, then you need to use the `multipart/related` MIME type defined in [RFC 2387](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387). Ask if you need help with this.)

Answer (score 0):

Attach the image and use html to display it. See the MIME example from your link for how to attach it. An `<img>` tag will do for display in most clients. Make sure you use the appropriate MIME type for html. Your link tells you how to do that too.